# android class async upload reference

Tags: java, android, class, reference

I am back from taking a few years break in programming. Today I am trying to access my webserver from android and I have some code I recycled from back in the day. The code used to work, but, lo and behold, today it has an error. Can someone help me figure this out?

Here is my main class:

```
public class login extends AppCompatActivity {
Button join;
TextView clientid;
EditText username, password;
_upload upload;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    upload = new _upload();
    String android_id = Secure.getString(login.this.getContentResolver(),
            Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    join = findViewById(R.id.join);
    clientid = findViewById(R.id.clientid);
    clientid.setText(android_id);
    username = findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = findViewById(R.id.password);
    join.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        login();
        }});
}
public void login(){
    String id = username.getText().toString();
    if (id.isEmpty()) { username.setError("required");username.requestFocus();return; }
    String pw = password.getText().toString();
    String cid = clientid.getText().toString();

    String[] params = new String[3];
    params[1]="username::" + id;
    params[2]="password::" + pw;
    params[3]="cid::" + cid;
    new upload.send(login.this, "dump.php", params);

    Toast.makeText(this, id + " " +pw+ " "+cid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}
```

}

my error is in the line `new upload.send(login.this, "dump.php", params);`

```
 error: cannot find symbol
        new _upload.send(login.this, "dump.php", params);
                   ^
  symbol:   class send
  location: class _upload
```

this is my second class, the one that used to work:

```
public class _upload extends AppCompatActivity {
HttpURLConnection conn = null;
String Return;
String homeurl = "removed";
String roomurl = "";
String param;
Context ctx;
String er;
public void location(Context context, String url, String params){
    ctx = context;
    roomurl = url;
    try {
        param = "lola=" + URLEncoder.encode(params, "UTF-8");
        new sendStatusChange_Server().execute("");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void send(Context context, String url, String params[]){
    ctx = context;
    roomurl = url;
    int total = params.length;
    int i = 0;
    while(i<=total-1) {
        if (i==0) {
            try {
                String[] keyval = params[0].split("::");
                param = keyval[0] + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(keyval[1], "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            i++;
        }
        else{
            try {
                String[] keyval = params[i].split("::");
                param = param + "&" + keyval[0] + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(keyval[1], "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    new sendStatusChange_Server().execute("");
}

public class sendStatusChange_Server extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            updateserver();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        if(er!=null){Toast.makeText(ctx, er, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
        else{Toast.makeText(ctx, Return, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
    }
}

private void updateserver() throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(homeurl + roomurl);
    try {
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(param.getBytes().length);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        out.print(param);
        Log.d("SENT:", param + " to " + url.toString());
        out.close();
        String response = "";
        Scanner inStream = new Scanner(conn.getInputStream());
        while (inStream.hasNextLine())
            response += (inStream.nextLine());
        inStream.close();
        Return = response;
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        er = ex.toString();
    }
    return;
}
```

}

the code still runs fine on the old program but I made a new package and want to get that rolling... why would this happen? Thank you for taking the time!

Comment: You should *never* create an Activity manually like that (`new _upload()`). And your code and error message are inconsistent, missing an `_`

Comment: i never had a problem with it before (creating background task) and the underscore is a copypaste error, i still have the same issue. do you have any recommendations going forward?

Comment: As far as I can tell from this code you have `_upload` extend `AppCompatActivity` - why is that? You aren't using it as an actual Activity in the code shown here, and it will cause all sorts of potential problems if you try to call Activity base class methods in it. As far as your package error, there isn't enough information here to be able to help you.

Comment: could it be that you meant to call `upload.send(...)` and not `new _upload.send(...)`? No reason to create a new instance there, and the latter isn't correct syntax anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much, I just had to drop the 'new'!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error. Use

```
upload.send(...)
```

instead of

```
new upload.send(...)
```

since `upload` is already an instance of your class.

You should probably also make it so `_upload` doesn't extend `AppCompatActivity` (just remove the `extends AppCompatActivity` from `public class _upload extends AppCompatActivity`).